# Kotlin - How do you constantly check for variable change on the other file?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm still new to Kotlin and I don't know if I'm doing it right. Any help will be appreciated.

My problem is that I want to constantly check for changes on ObjectDetectorHelper.detectionTextStateFlow then assign that value on an EditText but all the flows on MainActivity only occurs one time

MainActivity.kt

```
    package org.tensorflow.lite.examples.objectdetection

import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.lifecycle.flowWithLifecycle
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import org.tensorflow.lite.examples.objectdetection.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import java.util.Locale

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    public lateinit var activityMainBinding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        activityMainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(activityMainBinding.root)
        val objectDetectorHelper = ObjectDetectorHelper(context=this, objectDetectorListener = null)
        
        lifecycleScope.launch{
            objectDetectorHelper.detectionTextStateFlow
                .flowWithLifecycle(lifecycle, Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
                .collect{
                    println("check")
                    activityMainBinding.etEditText.setText(
objectDetectorHelper.detectionTextStateFlow.toString())
                }
        }

        /*

        lifecycleScope.launch{
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED){
                    launch {
                        objectDetectorHelper.detectionTextStateFlow.collect{
                          
                            activityMainBinding.etEditText.setText("Try")
                        }
                    }
            }

        }*/
    }
```

ObjectDetectorHelper.kt

```
package org.tensorflow.lite.examples.objectdetection

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.os.SystemClock
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import kotlinx.coroutines.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import org.tensorflow.lite.gpu.CompatibilityList
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.ImageProcessor
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.TensorImage
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.ops.Rot90Op
import org.tensorflow.lite.task.core.BaseOptions
import org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.detector.Detection
import org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.detector.ObjectDetector
import org.tensorflow.lite.examples.objectdetection.MainActivity
import org.tensorflow.lite.examples.objectdetection.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class ObjectDetectorHelper(
  var threshold: Float = 0.5f,
  var numThreads: Int = 2,
  var maxResults: Int = 1,
  var currentDelegate: Int = 0,
  var currentModel: Int = 0,
  val context: Context,
  val objectDetectorListener: DetectorListener?,
) {
    val detectionTextStateFlow = MutableStateFlow<String>("")
    // For this example this needs to be a var so it can be reset on changes. If the ObjectDetector
    // will not change, a lazy val would be preferable.
    private var objectDetector: ObjectDetector? = null

    init {
        setupObjectDetector()
    }

    fun clearObjectDetector() {
        objectDetector = null
    }

    // Initialize the object detector using current settings on the
    // thread that is using it. CPU and NNAPI delegates can be used with detectors
    // that are created on the main thread and used on a background thread, but
    // the GPU delegate needs to be used on the thread that initialized the detector
    fun setupObjectDetector() {
        // Create the base options for the detector using specifies max results and score threshold
        val optionsBuilder =
            ObjectDetector.ObjectDetectorOptions.builder()
                .setScoreThreshold(threshold)
                .setMaxResults(maxResults)

        // Set general detection options, including number of used threads
        val baseOptionsBuilder = BaseOptions.builder().setNumThreads(numThreads)

        // Use the specified hardware for running the model. Default to CPU
        when (currentDelegate) {
            DELEGATE_CPU -> {
                // Default
            }
            DELEGATE_GPU -> {
                if (CompatibilityList().isDelegateSupportedOnThisDevice) {
                    baseOptionsBuilder.useGpu()
                } else {
                    objectDetectorListener?.onError("GPU is not supported on this device")
                }
            }
            DELEGATE_NNAPI -> {
                baseOptionsBuilder.useNnapi()
            }
        }

        optionsBuilder.setBaseOptions(baseOptionsBuilder.build())

        val modelName =
            when (currentModel) {
                MODEL_CUSTOM -> "detect.tflite"
                // -> "mobilenetv1.tflite"
                //MODEL_EFFICIENTDETV0 -> "efficientdet-lite0.tflite"
                //MODEL_EFFICIENTDETV1 -> "efficientdet-lite1.tflite"
                //MODEL_EFFICIENTDETV2 -> "efficientdet-lite2.tflite"
                else -> "detect.tflite"
            }

        try {
            objectDetector =
                ObjectDetector.createFromFileAndOptions(context, modelName, optionsBuilder.build())
        } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
            objectDetectorListener?.onError(
                "Object detector failed to initialize. See error logs for details"
            )
            Log.e("Test", "TFLite failed to load model with error: " + e.message)
        }
    }

    suspend fun emitObject(string: String) {
        detectionTextStateFlow.emit(string)
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    fun detect(image: Bitmap, imageRotation: Int) {
        if (objectDetector == null) {
            setupObjectDetector()
        }


        // Inference time is the difference between the system time at the start and finish of the
        // process
        var inferenceTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()

        // Create preprocessor for the image.
        // See https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/
        //            lite_support#imageprocessor_architecture
        val imageProcessor =
            ImageProcessor.Builder()
                .add(Rot90Op(-imageRotation / 90))
                .build()

        // Preprocess the image and convert it into a TensorImage for detection.
        val tensorImage = imageProcessor.process(TensorImage.fromBitmap(image))

        val results = objectDetector?.detect(tensorImage)
        inferenceTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - inferenceTime
        objectDetectorListener?.onResults(
            results,
            inferenceTime,
            tensorImage.height,
            tensorImage.width)

//HERE IS WHERE I ASSIGN THE VALUE
        if(!results.isNullOrEmpty())
        {
            detectionTextStateFlow.value = results[0].categories[0].label
        }

    }

    interface DetectorListener {
        fun onError(error: String)
        fun onResults(
          results: MutableList<Detection>?,
          inferenceTime: Long,
          imageHeight: Int,
          imageWidth: Int
        )
    }

    companion object {
        const val DELEGATE_CPU = 0
        const val DELEGATE_GPU = 1
        const val DELEGATE_NNAPI = 2
        const val MODEL_CUSTOM = 0
        //const val MODEL_MOBILENETV1 = 1
        //const val MODEL_EFFICIENTDETV0 = 2
        //const val MODEL_EFFICIENTDETV1 = 3
        //const val MODEL_EFFICIENTDETV2 = 4
    }
}
```

Comment: You activity is already subscribed to the changes thru `lifecycleScope.launch{
         .. .flowWithLifecycle(lifecycle, Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
                .collect{..}` . The problem probably is the producer logic  -  note that your current  `fun detect()` implementation only updates `detectionTextStateFlow` everytime the function is called. I suggest you to try  some codelabs on using kotlin flows for updating the ui state to have a better understanding on the subject matter.

Comment: Hi again. I've tried the following code: 
`.collect{
                    activityMainBinding.etEditText.hint = objectDetectorHelper.detectionTextStateFlow.toString()
                }`

The edit text hint becomes `kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlowImpl@bg6bb07`

Comment: use `...hint = it`